# How can I interface a Python function with Matlab?

Tags: python, matlab, simulink

I have a simulink electric motor example that is being controlled via PWM.

I want the controller that spits out the PWM to be a Python function ( a NN controller I have written in Python INPUT: motor rpm OUT: PWM signal) -- and it returns in real time floating point numbers. e.g. 2,504; 2,103 etc.

I want that to be the input for the PWM block in the Simulink model. And the output of the electric motor (rpm) to be the input for the Python function (I have a special measurement input for that function).

Has anybody had any succes with linking .py files and Simulink ?

---

And to run the python files, do I need to containerize them or to do something special ? Because there are 5 files in the whole project which I will need. I cannot run the function alone.

Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Does your question really need the [tag:matlab-compiler] and [tag:simscape] tags? They seem irrelevant to me

Comment: How do I remove them?

Comment: You would have to [edit] your question and remove the tags at the bottom. I already did it for you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, choose your main entry point environment, either matlab or python.
You can call one from the other with the [matlab/python interface](https://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/python-language.html?s_tid=CRUX_lftnav).

Let's assume you are more familiar with matlab. Then I suggest you to include a [matlab function block](https://it.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/matlabfunction.html?searchHighlight=matlab%20function&s_tid=srchtitle_matlab%20function_4) in your model which will be responsible for the control part. In here, insert the matlab/python interface code, calling the python function with the NN and getting the input to be applied to the model.

This is the fastest way I can think to do this.

Comment: Thanks! I tried and managed to get easier functions to work but no really complex Py functions

Comment: I the answer satisfies you, please upvote it or accept it, It will help everyone. Thanks again!